# Azure App Registration - IAM under Subscription doesnt show my app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Problem Description:

I need to add a new app registration for an integration with an application.
I go ahead and create an app registration with minimal details like web redirect URL, owners etc.

Now I would like to add certain permissions to the app using the subscription > (Access Control) IAM and under role assignment, I am not able to find my app unlike others.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Thanks,
Akshay

Comment: What do you enter to search for your app? The name of the app is required here.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this situation before, please make sure your app and the subscription are in the same Azure AD tenant, then just refresh the portal and search for the app name again, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - my app showed up after I left the computer and came back in an hour. I guess the replication of the identities from the app into being able to select from the IAM screen takes awhile.